# How to store lines typed on command line into a buffer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, buffer

I am trying to make a command to create text files on the command line for my operating system. The user types text, presses enter, types some more, and presses enter twice when the text is finished to create the file. The problem is that only the first line typed is being stored into the buffer.

```
int i=0;
int buffTotal=0;
char textLine[80];
char buffer[13312];

syscall(1, textLine) //user enters line of text which is stored in textLine

while(textLine[i] != 0xa) //0xa is the character appended to end of text typed in textLine
{
     buffer[i] = textLine[i];
     i++;
}
buffTotal+=80;

while(textLine[0] != 0x0A) //0X0A would be the first char in the array if user typed enter twice
{
     i=0;
     syscall(1, textLine);

     while(textLine[i] != 0xa)
     {
          buffer[buffTotal+i] = textLine[i];
          i++;
     }
     buffTotal+=80;
}
syscall(0,buffer); //this prints out the buffer
```

Comment: It is impossible for us to debug such incomplete code. Please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem. Please also provide the exact test input, expected output/result and actual output/result.

Comment: This is as minimal and complete as I can get it without copy pasting mountains of code. It's less about the debugging of the code present and more about if I'm going about this the right way.

Comment: It's not complete in the sense that we can't compile the code to run it. It's very important to have such code because you may not even be showing the code that causes the problem. Without a minimal, complete and verifiable example there is no point posting on Stackoverflow as it is likely to go unanswered or will waste people's time trying to debug without the right info. Please read that link for further explanation.

Comment: The choice of 13 KiB for the buffer size is intriguing; what made you choose that?  Using `buffTotal += 80;` seems odd; there's no obvious guarantee that the lines are 80 characters long.    How do you know that the input operation was successful?  I'm not convinced about the "0x0A would be the first char" comment.  It is better to use `'\n'` than `'\x0A'` or `0x0A` or `'\012'` or `012` — the newline escape code is more recognizable (and reliable, though the places where 0x0A isn't reliable are few and far between these days).

Comment: The buffer size is that because it's the max size of a file for my operating system. It can only have 26 sectors and each sector is 512 bytes long, so 512*26 = 13312. Also, I changed buffTotal+= 80 to buffTotal+= i and it works now, so thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 0):

by reading your question, i think you want to:
 1. create a command which creates a text file.
 2. also it takes text from user.

Assuming that you are using Linux, you can easily achieve this by the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char c;
  if(argc<2)
  {
    printf("enter file name.\n");
    return;
  }
  FILE* fp=fopen(argv[1],"w");
  while((c=getchar())!='`') // terminating character is `
  {
    putc(c,fp);
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

after compilation, you can create alias for running the program.
[output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L82TM.png)